# Get the Field Name and Value : Array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using *mysql_fetch_assoc* but:

```
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future
```

php.net recommends *MySQLi or PDO_MySQL*

I tried `mysqli_fetch_assoc` but don't know how to get the actual Field Name (Attribute) and the corresponding Value.

Assuming I have only 1 row of User Information:

**E.g.** Results field names: "Name" and "Age"  and  Values: "John" and "18".

My goal is to get the actual field name (Name and Age) and at the same time to get the value of specific field name on the same loop like $column['Name'] or $column['Age'].

Example sql inside an existing loop:

```
$sqlUpdate = "Update report SET `" . $key. "` = " . $value . " where Name = '" . $value . "'"
```

.

because if I'll just use $value how will I know what field name I am referring to in `...where Name = '" . $value . "'"?`

This is for report purposes only where the records within other table's rows are the field names (columns) of my other table.

Hope this explains more about my concern.

by the way mysql_fetch_assoc and mysqli_fetch_assoc are just my way of telling someone that might have enough knowledge if these extensions (old or new) is still useful to solve my concern.

Comment: An associative array already has all this information -- names as keys, values as values. What's the problem?

Comment: There is not a 1-1 transition between `ext/mysql` functions and mysqli functions/methods or PDO methods.  I don't know why anyone would ever choose `mysqli` over `PDO`, but there are certainly tutorials for the former.  http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: mysqli in procedural mode is almost a 1:1 drop-in replacement for mysql. about you really need to do is add `i` to all the function calls.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. mysqli_fetch_assoc works exactly the same way as it's mysql_* counterpart. If mysql_fetch_assoc works okay for you - mysqli will do it as well. The rest of your question is the same unclear

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value){ echo $key .' ' . $value;}` that should give you an hint

Comment: explain expected output with an example.

Comment: @YourCommonSense will try to simplify more about my query. sorry for that

Comment: @HugoDozois  I've added more info . thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not use mysqli. Use PDO instead.
   Everyone is urging you to move from mysql_ doing it only for sake of prepared statements but mysqli is unusable with them.
2. As it was said in the comments, an associative array already has all this information -- names as keys, values as values. No matter where it came from - mysql, mysqli or manually created array:

.

```
$arr['Name'] = 'John';
```

So, you can have your key various ways.

```
$key = key($arr); // $key="Name" now
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {  // another way to get keys and values.
    echo $key .' ' . $value;
}
$keys = array_keys($arr); // $keys=array('Name'); now
```

But I have a feeling that your problem is siomewhere else but you just can't properly explain it.
What is your final goal? Why do you need that field name?